# Java arraylist of different object class

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

i have an issue with the understanding the arraylist which contain the objects from different classes. I have 6 objects. All of objects have 2 attributes in common.(ID,Type)
Every object has its own attributes. I created mainObject class with 2 atr (ID,Type). The other objects extends the mainObject so they have

```
class mainClass{
    this.id=id;
    this.type=type;
}
class extendedClass extends mainClass{
    super(ID,Type);
    this.atr1=atr1;
}

class extendedClass2 extends mainClass{
    super(ID,type);
    this.atr2=atr2;
    this.atr3=atr3;
}
```

I read the informations from file.

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("data.txt");
// Get the object of DataInputStream
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String strLine;
// Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // Print the content on the console
    String s[] = strLine.split("\\|");
    mainClass myObj = new mainClass(s[0], s[1]);

ArrayList<mainClass> items = new ArrayList<mainClass>();
items.add(myObj);
```

I need all objects to be readed from file line by line and store them in the array list.
How should i do this? I tried the `ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>`, but its not working. The point is read all the objects from file, sort them due to chosen attribute(id,type).

Comment: start with `ArrayList<MainClass>`.

Comment: What's the problem with your code. Looks like it could work.

Comment: @Serv0: Your sample classes don't really compile, the code would have to be put inside a constructor...

Comment: You need to make sure you have braces in the right place and indent correctly. It's not clear where the while loop ends.

Comment: @JanDvorak
i could do this:
[code]while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
  String s[] = strLine.split("\\|");
  ItemObject myObj = new ItemObject(s[0], s[1]);
 ArrayList<mainClass> items = new ArrayList<mainClass>(); 
   items.add(myObj);
  for(ItemObject temp : items){
System.out.println("id :"+temp.getID()+"Type :"+temp.getObjectType()); 
     } 
    }'[code]
but then only mainClass attributes will be stored in the list how can i access the other attributes. If the arraylist type is mainClass a don't have access to the other class functions f.e. getAtr3()?

temp.getClass.???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that you need a list of `mainClass`:

```
ArrayList<mainClass> items = new ArrayList<mainClass>();
```

However you should put this line before the while loop, not inside it.

```
ArrayList<mainClass> items = new ArrayList<mainClass>();

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // etc...
    items.add(myObj);
}
```